# What does the word 'above all' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase 'above all' mean?

Does it mean 'especially'?

Context:

> This condition of co-nascence applies, **above all**, to consciousness and
> its concomitant mental phenomena, such as feeling, perception,
> volition, sense-impression, attention, etc.

Source: P.29

''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Answer (score 3):

I think you could simply look it up in a dictionary.

It means **more than anything** or **most importantly.**

Answer (score 2):

It is stronger than "especially".

In this context, the implication is that the condition of co-nascence could apply to many things. Examples might be, emotions, thoughts, sensations, and so on. But then the writer is saying that although co-nascence may well apply to all those things, the thing that it *most* applies to, or that it applies to *most of all*, is consciousness (and its concomitant processes...).

If you imagine arranging in a list the various things to which co-nascent might apply, then the writer wants to place "consciousness" as the top item on that list -- i.e. literally *above all* of the other items.

Comment: Thanks you very much, @tkp.